# django unicode convert to japanese

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I create one table member, which contains one field 'name' which need to store Japanese. I use web service to visit the table data. Below is the code,

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders it's content into JSON.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

from rest_framework import serializers
class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('member_id', 'name', 'homepage', 'map')

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        """
        Create or update a new Member instance, given a dictionary
        of deserialized field values.

        Note that if we don't define this method, then deserializing
        data will simply return a dictionary of items.
        """
        if instance:
            # Update existing instance
            instance.member_id = attrs.get('member_id', instance.member_id)
            instance.name = attrs.get('name', instance.name)
            instance.homepage = attrs.get('homepage', instance.homepage)
            instance.map = attrs.get('map', instance.map)
            return instance

        # Create new instance
        return Member(**attrs)

//snapshot code
serializer = MemberSerializer(member)
return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

The 'name' value displays as unicode , {"name": "\u691c\u8a3a\u3092\u4e88\u7d04\u3059\u308b"}. How can I convert it to Japanese?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: You still haven't made it clear what you mean by "The 'name' value displays as…". Displays where? When you do what? What you've shown us is a perfectly valid representation of a Unicode string with 7 Japanese characters in it. If you want a _different_ representation… you have to tell us what you're doing to getting that representation, and in what context, before we can tell you what to do to get a different representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a [`UnicodeJSONRenderer`](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers.html#unicodejsonrenderer). `JSONRenderer` escapes non-ascii characters with `\u` syntax; `UnicodeJSONRenderer` won't do that.

Comment: Misunderstood the problem a bit. Try a `UnicodeJSONRenderer`.

Comment: That's not the problem. As you can see, he is getting a proper string back, it's just that he's printing the `repr` rather than the `str` of that string.

Comment: @abarnert: I actually thought that was the problem at first, but after taking another look at the code and the REST documentation, it looks like that's actually not the case. If it were a matter of `str` vs `repr`, Python 2.7 would be showing a `u` in front of the unicode string.

Comment: @user2357112: In that case… it's quite possible that there _is_ no problem, and he's just looking at the data wrong. Since we don't know what "The 'name' value displays as unicode" (displays where? how is he checking?), it's hard to say.

Comment: Maybe I need explain more clearly, I created a simple web service as the above described. The mobile user can make request to get data. Now I use curl to do the test, the json object show raw unicode data, not Japanese, I am afraid that the user will see the unicode data, not Japanese, so I want to convert unicode to Janpanese.

Comment: When you say "the json object show raw unicode data"… where is that showing? In your logs? In a `print` statement?

Comment: In curl and firefox's response, I am just afraid that the mobile client will display just unicode, not Japanese, so I want to display Japanese in json object, not unicode

Comment: Did you parse the JSON?

Comment: no, I just tried with Java, the string "\u691c\u8a3a\u3092\u4e88\u7d04\u3059\u308b" print as 検診を予約する. My concern is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The string already *is* in Japanese. It contains 7 Unicode characters, each of which is a Japanese character.

The problem is that when you take the `str` of a dict or other collection (which is what happens when you `print` it out), it includes the *repr* of each member of the collection, not the *str*.

To see the difference:

```
>>> s = u"\u691c\u8a3a\u3092\u4e88\u7d04\u3059\u308b"
>>> print str(s)
検診を予約する
>>> print repr(s)
u'\u691c\u8a3a\u3092\u4e88\u7d04\u3059\u308b'
```

Now:

```
>>> ss = [s]
>>> print str(ss)
[u'\u691c\u8a3a\u3092\u4e88\u7d04\u3059\u308b']
>>> print repr(ss)
[u'\u691c\u8a3a\u3092\u4e88\u7d04\u3059\u308b']
```

If you just want to `print` it or `log` it, there are numerous questions on SO, and an entry in the official Python FAQ, about how to get the `str` for elements inside a collection, but the basic idea is: explicitly call `str` on them.

If you want to embed it into a page that you've created as, say, UTF-8 or Shift-JIS, just `.encode('utf-8')` or `.encode('shift-jis')` it. (However, it's worth noting that with recent versions of Django, especially in Python 3.x, it's better to do everything as Unicode and let Django worry about encoding at the end.)

If you want to embed it in JSON, and the code on the other side of the pipe is getting confused, it may help to explicitly `.encode('utf-8')` it. But that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: print str(s), got the exception in python2.7. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: But just 'print s' display the Japanese

Comment: OK, that means that `s` is actually a `unicode` object. In 2.7, calling `str(s)` on a `unicode` will try to encode it to `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, which is usually `ASCII`. But the idea is the same: you don't want to call `repr` on each string, so you can't just `print` a collection containing `unicode`s any more than you can just `print` a collection containing `str`s.